# Is there a quicker alternative for the [name=!] command?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m trying to make a multiplayer mini-game map. The solo player can activate command blocks to give harmful effects to everyone but themself. I’m using the [name=!] command, but I was wondering if there was something more efficient? If the roles of players were to rotate, say, if someone new became the solo player, is there a better way than re-inputting the new player’s name every time? Or am I stuck using the command I already use?
Apologies if this was confusing.

Comment: In MCJava you can for example use [tags](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/tag), I don't know if they exist in MCBE. If they don't, then scoreboards probably do at least. Also, "[name=!]" is not a command, it's a part of a target selector that can be used in commands. And if I understand your question correctly, you don't actually want a "quicker" way to do anything, but a more general one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tags, or this command: `effect @a[c=!1] poison 100 1`
The `c=` means closest players, so `c=2` is the closest 2 players, and `c=!1` means not the closest one player.